# gunicorn - up and running but doesn't respond

Tags: python, monitoring, gunicorn

I've been running my python server side with gunicorn for awhile and it worked perfectly

today it stopped returning results for some api calls, I `pkill gunicorn` and run with debug as `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:xxxx` everything works fine

I have 2 questions:

1. is there a way to create a log file of calls (like the output of runserver)
2. is there a way to monitor my server?

Comment: is your gunicorn public facing or behind a proxy server like nginx?

Comment: if i'm not wrong  behind a proxy server like nginx

Answer (score 1):

Use `--log-file=-` to output the errors in the command line (stderr), for example:

```
gunicorn base.wsgi -c config.conf --log-file=-
```